# Different initial BASH prompt

Tags: bash

This is somewhat of a cosmetic (and trivial) question, but I suppose it may be useful to others than myself.  I've been playing around with the $PS1 variable in my ~/.bashrc, and I was wondering if there was any way to have the first prompt be slightly different than every other prompt.  More specifically, so far I have:

`PS1='\n\[\e[0;37m\][\[\e[0;35m\]\t\[\e[0;37m\]] \[\e[0;36m\]\u@\h \[\e[0;37m\][\[\e[1;34m\]\W\[\e[0;37m\]] \[\e[0;36m\]\$ \[\e[0m\]'`

but I don't want the newline at the beginning to display on the first prompt (and I could extend this to have the first prompt include more info, etc.).  I'm using gnome-terminal, if that makes a difference.

Is this at all possible?  And if so, how?

Comment: I answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859148/how-to-set-a-conditional-newline-in-ps1/14860632#14860632) with a too-clever variation on garyjohn's answer.

Comment: This would work, but I still want my PROMPT_COMMAND to work for other parts of $PS1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use bash's PROMPT_COMMAND. For example, you could put the following in your ~/.bashrc (or execute it at the command line while you experiment).

```
set_ps()
{
    if [ -z "$PSFLAG" ]
    then
        # Set first prompt
        PS1='first prompt: '
        PSFLAG=1
    else
        # Set other prompt
        PS1='other prompt: '
    fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=set_ps
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but instead I just inserted a variable into my $PS1 that gets set for the second prompt and then persists.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want some characters to be output before the first prompt and never again, why don’t you just have `.bashrc` output them?

Comment: The OP wanted *fewer* characters in the first prompt, i.e., no newline at the beginning.